# Is it correct to say "was spent in" when talking about a day or a moment?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

I would like to know if it's correct to say "was spent" when talking about a moment or a time in the day, and not about people, in a sentence.

For instance:

> The rest of the evening was spent in a joyous and relaxed atmosphere !

I know you can say "I have spent my evening/day doing this or/that" but I am not sure if I can put "the evening" or "the day" as the main subject, without referring to people.

Comment: Do you think is correct or incorrect? Why do you think that? What research have you done that supports your opinion?

Comment: HI Arlette ,welcome to ELL. If people make a comment about your question, please edit the question itself rather than adding updates as an answer.  You can edit your question using the **Edit** button below your question. I'll do it for now, but next time.... btw, There is no need to apologize for your mistakes. We understand that you are here to learn.

Comment: It's fine to say that a ***day*** or ***evening*** was spent ***in** [some state]* or ***doing** [some activity]*. But a ***moment*** is too short a time to be "spent" doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put "The rest of the evening" at that start of the sentence.

A normal sentence is in **active voice**. Here is an example:

> I spent the evening at home.

You can turn it into a **passive voice** sentence by removing the subject and moving the object to the front:

> The evening was spent at home.

In a passive voice sentence, the active-voice subject is called the **agent** and the active-voice object is called the **patient**. In the above sentence, the agent is missing and the patient is "The evening".

You can add the agent, but if you need an agent, you should think hard about whether you should be using passive voice at all.

> The evening was spent at home **by me**.

Passive voice is useful when we don't know who the agent is, or it's not important to specify, or if the really important part is the patient. You can read more about passive voice [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/passives).